# condition in sql query c

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I have

`tbl_ticket_categories(id , category_name , description , site_referers_id)`

`tbl_ticket_repliers(id , user_id , category_id , site_referers_id)`

`tbl_users(id , role_id , username , password )`

I want to select all `category_name` and `description` from `tbl_ticket_categories` where `site_referers_id = 1`

and also those `username` whose `user_id` is in `tbl_ticket_repliers`.

Answer (score 1):

```
select category_name,description,username from tbl_ticket_categories as ttc
join tbl_ticket_repliers as ttr on ttr.category_id=ttc.id
join tbl_users as tu on tu.id=ttc.user_id
where site_referers_id = 1
```

This is the query you get the exact result check it once

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT category_name, description, tu.username 
   FROM tbl_ticket_categories tc 
     INNER JOIN tbl_ticket_repliers tr 
        ON tc.id = tr.category_id
     INNER JOIN tbl_users tu 
        ON tr.user_id = tu.id
   WHERE tc.site_referers_id = 1
```

## [*See this fiddle*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b23b4/3)